# I need to learn Idempiere from the scratch. How should I do that?

Tags: idempiere

All my attempts have failed so far.

I expect to become an Idempiere expert eventually.

Also, I've been unable to install Idempiere on my laptop with Ubuntu OS so far. The one available on Github isn't good enough.

Also, making sense of various utilities has been too much of a challenge for me.

Answer (score 1):

i am same like you still in learning to develop iDempiere and want to become expert :)

First you need to learn is ERP, Idempiere are ERP Machine so you need to know what ERP is. And after you know what kind ERP is you need to try iDempiere and make iDempiere really familiar with you. After you and iDempiere know each other now time to develop.

this link will help you :

1. [This link will help you to setup your workspace to develop iDempiere](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Developing_Plug-Ins_-_Setup_the_workspace)
2. [And this link is the first step make you become iDempiere dev :)](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Developing_plug-ins_without_affecting_the_trunk)

And if you want to ask please ask in [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/idempiere)

Thanks